# Troubles with Arrays and strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
//libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  srand ( time(NULL) ); //initialize the random seed


  const char arrayNum[4] = {'5', '6', '7', '8'};
  int RandIndex = rand() % 4; //generates a random number between 0 and
  cout << arrayNum[RandIndex];
  int ceva = arrayNum[RandIndex] ;

  if (ceva == 6){

    cout << "hey";

  }

  else{

    cout << "nu";

  }

}
```

The code is showing only "nu" and it's not working properly.
If `arrayNum[RandIndex]` is equal to 6 show "hey" if else show "nu"

Comment: Try `if (ceva == '6')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem resides in the type of your array, I'll try to explain it:

Since your array is of type `char`, you are storing a character, not a number, which is ok. But then you're assigning the character to a int in

```
int ceva = arrayNum[RandIndex];
```

When you assign a character to a number, at least in C, it doesn't assign the number directly, but the the decimal representation of the encoding of the character.

So if you do `int i = '0'`, for example, in [unicode](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec), it will assign to i `48`, which is it's decimal representation.

Now, for the solution:

1. The easy and 'proper' way should be to change the array to numbers, not characters, or changing the if in order to compare to a character.
2. If for some reason you can't do 1., when assigning the character to the number do `- '0'`, so it looks like `int ceva = arrayNum[RandIndex] - '0'`. That will do the hack since, for `'1'` (unicode), you're doing `49 - 48`, for `'2'` = `50 - 48`, ...

Comment: What's an "ASCII hex"?  `'0'` may have a value of 48 on your (ASCII) system, but remember that C++ (and C) can work with any encoding, so `'0'` could be 240, or indeed any other `char` value.  Portable code doesn't usually need to know, of course.

Comment: _“The easy and 'proper' way should be to change the array to numbers, not characters”_ Why not the opposite way? It should also work for the OP’s example. IMHO both ways are correct.

Comment: `48` is not a hexadecimal code for `0`, but a decimal one.

Comment: HolyBlackCat: thanks, completely right! I misread the columns of the man ascii pages hehe. || 
TobySpeight: I didn't know that, thanks! I'll edit the answer to be more accurate || 
Melebius: You're right, I'll add that too